# lambda:UploadFunction not available under IAM Create Policy on AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, travis-ci, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am relatively new on AWS IAM policies and currently I am trying to create a policy under the AWS console so then I can copy it on to my Terraform file (since I keep getting "MalformedPolicyDocument" errors).

I am trying to allow permissions for kinesis to work with lambda and also travis to work with lambda. What I see in some places is that I should add lambda:UploadFunction as an Action for travis to work (e. g. https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/755/files) However when I am on the console Policy Generator there isn't such option under AWS Service: AWS Lambda.

[image]

I will try to add it anyway and see what happens but I just would like a clarification whether I am confusing things or if the console doesn't have all lambda action options available.

Comment: There is no API method called `lambda:UploadFunction`. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Operations.html

Comment: I think you are looking for `lambda:CreateFunction` and maybe `lambda:UpdateFunctionCode`

Comment: If you truly want to upload a .zip file of code -- you will likely also need `s3:PutObject`